# How do I change permissions for Windows\Temp?

Tags: windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change permissions for Windows\Temp?](https://superuser.com/questions/194845/how-do-i-change-permissions-for-windows-temp)

I am running Windows Vista Ultimate and I want to change the permissions in Windows\Temp.

For example, I want to remove the read-only attribute in General. When I do this I get an error that reads, "You will need to provide administrator permission to change these attributes." When I click continue, it does something but the Read-only box is still partially checked.

How do I take control of Windows\Temp?