# How do I change permissions for Windows\Temp?

Tags: windows-vista

I am running Windows Vista Ultimate and I want to change the permissions in Windows\Temp.

For example, I want to remove the read-only attribute in General.   When I do this I get an error that reads, "You will need to provide administrator permission to change these attributes."  When I click continue, it does something but the Read-only box is still partially checked.

How do I take control of Windows\Temp?

Comment: Are you local admin on the computer?

Comment: @r0ca: I think so.  This is my home PC.

Answer (score 1):

That is because this attribute is inherited from the Windows folder. Unless you mess with the attributes on the Windows folder also - which is a bad idea - i think you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot into the computer using a Linux LiveCD and making said folder writeable or just doing whatever options you wanted to do in the folder directly from the LiveCD.